# Execute url by WebView.goBack

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-webview, jsoup

I'm stack in following problem! I parse website, and here is my approximate code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
String CurURL = "";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    webview.setWebViewClient(new ForumWebViewClient());
    new ParseMyPageTask().execute(url);
    }
    private class ForumWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webview, String url) {
        new ParseMyPageTask().execute(url);
        return true;
    }
    }

    public class ParseMyPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                    *JSoup work*
        return result;
            }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("http:..", result, "text/html", "UTF-8", CurURL);
    }
    }
    @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (webview.canGoBack()) {
        webview.goBack();
        return;
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}
}
```

What should i do for AsyncTask execute url after back button pressed? Now it return page as it is, not parsed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manipulate [WebBackForwardList](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebBackForwardList.html) to load your URL, not the ones automatically cached by WebView by default.

You do that by overriding `WebView.goBack()`:

```
  @Override
  public void goBack() {
    WebBackForwardList temp = copyBackForwardList();
    for (int i=0; i<temp.getSize(); i++) {
      WebHistoryItem item = temp.getItemAtIndex(i);
      // do whatever you want here...
    }

    // do whatever you want here...
    super.goBack();
  }
```